# How many processes this code going to generate?

Tags: c, process

I am not sure how many processes going to be created in this program? I suppose there is going to be created three child process in a while loop. Then, each child process is going to fork two times which means there are going to be two child process plus the one created by that child process is also going to fork and there is going to be 4 child process for each state. In total, there are 12 processes. Is that true?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
 pid_t childpid;
 int i=0;
 while((childpid>0) && (i<3))
 {
      childpid=fork();
      i++;
 }
 if(childpid==0){
      fork();
      fork();
 }
 exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Trace it on paper. It's what I did back in Uni when learning about operating system design

Comment: I think I have seen that snippet of code last week....

Comment: `pid_t childpid = getpid();` is missing.

Comment: Eventhough we create it by using pid_t, do we still need it? @J.F.Sebastian

Comment: it is "undefined behavior" in C: *"The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.9, 6.8)."* `childpid > 0` in your code may start WWIII.

Comment: What about C++? Is it valid?@J.F.Sebastian

Comment: it is UB in C++ too. `pid_t` is a POD type: it is a signed integral type and therefore `pid_t childpid;` makes its value "indeterminate"—it is UB to use such values (due to "trap representation").

Answer (score 0):

The total number of processes is 13

```
 while((childpid>0) && (i<3))
```

will only execute for the parent since the fork() system call returns the pid of the child to the parent process and a 0 to the child process.

Thus the while loop will generate 3 child processes with the childpid variable value 0, and the main parent process which now has the childpid variable value equal to that of the last forked child.

Total processes till now 4

For the condition

```
if(childpid==0){
      fork();
      fork();
 }
```

each child process from before spawns 1 child in the first fork call. The second fork will spawn another two new processes from the two proceeses of the first fork. So for each child process we will have spawned processes a total of 3 new processes.
Thus for th 3 child processes from the while loop, we will generate 9 new processes.

So total number of processes would be 4 + 9 = 13